# Pass value to jquery dialog

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I've got an asp.net gridview wrapped around an update panel with say two fields:

```
<asp:TemplateField Visible="False">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" style="display:none" 
      Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.ID") %>' Width=".05px">
    </asp:Label>
  </ItemTemplate>
  <ItemStyle Width="1%" />
  <ControlStyle Width="0px" />
  <HeaderStyle Width="0px" />
</asp:TemplateField>

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="#">
  <ItemTemplate>
  <asp:HyperLink ID="hlSortOrder" runat="server" CssClass="hlDialog" NavigateUrl="javascript:return false;"
    Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.SortOrder") %>'>
  </asp:HyperLink>
  </ItemTemplate>
  <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
  <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
  <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
</asp:TemplateField>
```

The second field is a hyperlink field where when I click on it I can open up the jquery ui dialog box.  I call it like so:

```
$(".hlDialog").click(function () {
    $('#dialog').dialog({
        draggable: true,
        modal: true,
        height: 600,
        width: 800,
        title: "Log file",
        open: function (type, data) {
            $(this).parent().appendTo("form");
        }
    });
});
```

This works fine however...Is it possible to pass the value of my first gridview (from above) `lblID` to the jquery dialog box?  Right now I am just pulling up an empty dialog screen.  I'd like to be able to eventually take the value of lblID (from the gridview above) and then pull some data to display on my dialog box.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Your modal window should have access to the DOM from the calling page. You should be able to use jquery on your modal window to retrieve lblID from the calling page.

Comment: You forgot to mention anything about how that might work. Try again.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, you can do something like below in the click event:

```
$(".hlDialog").click(function () {
    // First parent() is for "td", next for "tr"
    var lblID = $(this).parent().parent().find("span").html();
 .
 .
 .
});
```

Hope this Helps!!

Comment: once I do have my value how can I call additional code to pull some data from say my database server? FOr instance, assume I have the dialog and I've pulled the value, I need to call server side code to get the details for this lblID. I can only do that in some sort of server event... –

Comment: You can call a WCF service or Web Method using ajax and get the data from your database.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the tutorial on http://blog.nemikor.com/2009/04/08/basic-usage-of-the-jquery-ui-dialog/

Mainly:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
        .html('This dialog will show every time!')
        .dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            title: 'Basic Dialog'
        });

    $('#opener').click(function() {
        $dialog.dialog('open');
        // prevent the default action, e.g., following a link
        return false;
    });
});
```

That will let you set the HTML in the dialog box. Get your lblID with DOM.

And using the value from another answer, you get it in DOM with something like:

```
var lblID = $(this).parent().parent().find("span").html();
```

Then use that value for your .html

```
.html(lblID)
```

Example is here: http://example.nemikor.com/basic-usage-of-the-jquery-ui-dialog/

Answer (score 0):

Try this on for size. I'm adding in a bit to your existing function because I'm not entirely sure what value you want where.

```
<% /* this field could be a simpler <asp:BoundField> or something similar... */ %>
<asp:TemplateField Visible="False">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" style="display:none" 
      Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.ID") %>' Width=".05px">
    </asp:Label>
  </ItemTemplate>
  <ItemStyle Width="1%" />
  <ControlStyle Width="0px" />
  <HeaderStyle Width="0px" />
</asp:TemplateField>

$(".hlDialog").click(function () {
    var that = $(this),
        thatValue = that.val(),
        lblIDValue = that.prev.text(), //should be accurate depending on what else is happening on the page
        aux = 0;

    $('#dialog').dialog({
        draggable: true,
        modal: true,
        height: 600,
        width: 800,
        title: "Log file",
        open: function (type, data) {
            var el = $('<div>').addClass('hiMom').text( thatValue + ' ' + lblIDValue );
            $(this).prepend(el).parent().appendTo("form");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: hi jcolebrand - this makes sense however, once I do have my value how can I call additional code to pull some data from say my database server?  FOr instance, assume I have the dialog and I've pulled the value, I need to call server side code to get the details for this `lblID`.  I can only do that in some sort of server event...

Comment: How would you propose to load the data from the server? If you're using raw asp.net WebForms then use a UpdatePanel and a Timer control, I suppose.